React Hook Form useFieldArray loses focus on input after typing - How to retain focus?
I'm using useFieldArray from React Hook Form to build a dynamic form where users can add or remove fields. However, I've run into an issue where the input field loses focus after typing in it. This happens specifically for the Link input in each dynamically added field.
Here’s a version of my component:
import axios from 'axios'; 
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useFieldArray, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import usePreview from '../../hooks/usePreview';
import { platforms } from '../../utils/platforms';

const DynamicForm = () => {
    const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    const apiConfig = {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    };
    const { preview, setPreview } = usePreview();
    const { register, control, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            links: preview?.links?.length
                ? preview.links
                : [{ platform: '', url: '' }],
        },
    });

    const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: 'links',
    });

    // Update form with preview values when preview changes
    useEffect(() => {
        if (preview?.links?.length) {
            reset({ links: preview.links });
        }
    }, [preview, reset]);

    const handleInputChange = (index, fieldName, value) => {
        // Update the field directly in fields array
        const updatedLinks = fields.map((field, i) =>
            i === index ? { ...field, [fieldName]: value } : field
        );
        setPreview({ links: updatedLinks });
    };

    const handleRemove = (index) => {
        // Remove the field from the form
        remove(index);

        // Remove the corresponding entry from preview state
        const updatedPreviewLinks = [...preview.links];
        updatedPreviewLinks.splice(index, 1); // Remove the item at the specified index
        setPreview({ links: updatedPreviewLinks });
    };

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/links', data, apiConfig);

            // Update only the "links" part of localStorage with the response
            const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
            userData.links = response.data.links; // Update the links array
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userData));

            console.log('Form submitted successfully:', response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-6">
            {/* Add New Link Button */}
            <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => append({ platform: '', url: '' })}
                className="block w-full bg-transparent text-brandColor font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-md border border-brandColor"
            >
                + Add new link
            </button>

            {fields.map((field, index) => (
                <div
                    key={field.id}
                    className="bg-gray-50 p-6 rounded-lg shadow-md relative"
                >
                    <h3 className="font-semibold text-lg mb-4">Link #{index + 1}</h3>
                    <div className="">
                        {/* Platform Selection */}
                        <div>
                            <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                Platform
                            </label>
                            <select
                                {...register(`links.${index}.platform`)}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                    handleInputChange(index, 'platform', e.target.value)
                                }
                                className="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                            >
                                <option value="">Select platform</option>
                                {platforms.map((platform) => (
                                    <option key={platform.platform} value={platform.platform}>
                                        {platform.platform.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                                            platform.platform.slice(1)}
                                    </option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        {/* Link URL Input */}
                        <div>
                            <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                Link
                            </label>
                            <input
                                {...register(`links.${index}.url`)}
                                type="url"
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                    handleInputChange(index, 'url', e.target.value)
                                }
                                className="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                                placeholder="https://example.com"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {/* Remove Button */}
                    {fields.length > 1 && (
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            onClick={() => handleRemove(index)}
                            className="absolute top-4 right-4 text-red-500 hover:text-red-700"
                        >
                            Remove
                        </button>
                    )}
                </div>
            ))}

            {/* Save Button */}
            <div className="flex justify-end mt-3">
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    className="w-fit bg-brandColor text-white font-bold py-2 px-6 rounded outline-none"
                >
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
};

export default DynamicForm;

How can I prevent the input from losing focus while typing when using useFieldArray in React Hook Form.
Thanks in advance!

You are both registering the inputs and controlling them.  You should only need to register them.  The onHandleInputChange should not be needed.
